# How to interact with YouTube commentators while maintaing Adsense on Youtube?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I'm sorry if the question sounds ambiguous, so let me clarify.  Google allows Adsense on a YouTube channel, specifically on a YouTube video.  Well Google monitors clicks on the ads so as to make sure it is not from you, okay fair enough, however what about impressions?  How can I interact with my YouTube commentators/subscribers without Google punishing me for a self impressions of my YouTube video?

In other words I HAVE TO view my own video in order for me to access the comment section to address a certain commentator.  Well as you know that counts as a "view" even if it was from me.  Well, logic suggest if I keep "viewing" my own videos Google may suspend my account.  Is there a limit to my own quote "views" to my videos so as to address my subscribers without punishment from Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're be logged in while commenting so your impressions won't count. Your views may temporary count but at the end of each month (23rd) the ads are recalculated and they remove self impressions.

Comment: Not saying I would, but that means I could theoretically view my own videos 100 times a day, and I won't get punished so long as I am logged in?

Comment: As long as your not intentional increasing the views then no, I been on YouTube for over 5 years and never had a problem commenting, Commenting is intentional and helps the rankings of your videos.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the excellent answer provided by @bybe, I would say that it's not a problem viewing your own videos while interacting with your audience - as long as you don't accidentally click on the ads while your video is playing. You can filter out your own views in Google Analytics if it's affecting your analytics statistics.